# Apache Camel maxMessagesPerPoll not working for ftp component

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel's FTP component to read files from an FTP server. I have built my input endpoint this way:

```
StringBuilder inputEndpointSb = new StringBuilder();
inputEndpointSb.append("ftp://");
inputEndpointSb.append(configProperties.getExternalServerHost()).append(":");
inputEndpointSb.append(configProperties.getExternalServerPort());
inputEndpointSb.append(configProperties.getExternalDirectory());
inputEndpointSb.append("?username=").append(configProperties.getExternalSftpUsername());
inputEndpointSb.append("&password=").append(configProperties.getExternalSftpPassword());
inputEndpointSb.append("&passiveMode=true");
inputEndpointSb.append("&maxMessagesPerPoll=40");
inputEndpointSb.append("&move=archive");
inputEndpointSb.append("&moveFailed=error");
String inputEndpoint = inputEndpointSb.toString();
```

My Route looks like below

```
from("direct:transferFile")
            .process(requestProcessor)
            .log("Transferring file")
            .loop(configProperties.getCompletionSize()).copy()
                .pollEnrich()
                    .simple("${exchangeProperty.inputEndpoint}").timeout(0).aggregationStrategy(requestAggregator)
                .choice()
                    .when(body().isNotNull())
                        .toD("${exchangeProperty.outputEndpoint}", true)
                        .log("File transferred")
                    .otherwise()
                        .log("Empty body, exiting");
```

I am calling the route from a spring boot scheduler.

So here I have added a parameter maxMessagesPerPoll. There are many files in my FTP server but I want my FTP consumer to consume 40 files in one go and transfer to destination. But when I run this program, the FTP consumer is picking up files one by one. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you post your route?

Comment: Your route looks fine. How do you know this BatchConsumer is not performing batching? If you look at delivery of exchanges in a route, it may look like there is no batching going on, unless you look at CamelBatchSize and CamelBatchComplete exchange properties.

Comment: <strike>Your route looks fine</strike> What I meant was the endpoint configuration. Sorry :|

Comment: I have provided my route